# Class containing strings - Can I skip initialising them and if so how?

Tags: c++, string, dynamic, class-members

happy coders!

I had a plan to try to learn some C++ today and so I thought I could take an old C assignment from a previous course and just do the same thing in C++. The assignment is to read music files and retrieve data from their ID3 tags and sort them in folders according to their artist, album and track title etc etc... this does not really matter but you know at least what I'm going for.

So I played around a little with sets and made my program receive an array of strings specifying different songs which it will loop the algorithm over.

In this next step I got stuck though due to how I tried to copy the behaviour of my old C program which was a struct containing three values being:

```
int size;
char *tag_name;
char *data;
```

but so far I have been unable to recreate this dynamic behaviour in C++ where I wish to only have the members defined but not initialised since I wanted to be able to change this data later on. Technically I can do this in a way where I get the data from the file before I create the tag, and therefore give the constructor their initial values and be done with it. But can I do it in the way I want to?

```
class Tag {
 public:
   std::string name;
   std::string data;
   int size;

   Tag() {}
   Tag(std::string n, std::string d, int s) : name(n), data(d), size(s) { }
   void setData(std::string data) { this.data = data }
};
```

Since I've tried a billion combinations of pointers and whatnot (Googled loads) I just returned to the above and decided to ask you how to actually accomplish this.

My brained is completely mashed but consider the above psuedo code since I bet it is not correct in any way...

So my question is:
How do I define a class so that I get a dynamic string allocation for the members name and data? I was almost thinking of using some good old char* but the point of me trying this was to learn some C++, so I am forcing myself to go through this now.

Comment: You can change the string anytime in C++

Comment: You shouldn't really need to do that. Maybe you could show the actual code?

Comment: I currently question a potential lack of `<string>` in your include list.

Comment: @BWG How does it affect the memory and time complexity if let's say I'd change this string by adding stuff to it? Does it work like a linked list or does it work like a char[] does in C? Meaning reallocation must take place?

Comment: What is `size` referring to? Possibly you really want `std::vector<uint8_t> data` ?

Comment: @Simon The rule of C++ is basically, don't worry about it. I assume an `std::string` just has an internal char array, so not a linked list. Don't worry about performance of the strings though.

Comment: @WhozCraig Don't worry about that. I have those things and so that is not the problem. I guess I'm just wondering how this is handled in the background and my C-brain was thinking I'd need to have a pointer or something so that the string could be dynamically assigned after creating the object. Which at first my compiler said I couldn't, but I can't remember what the actual code looked like then since I've changed it back and forth for a while now.

Comment: @BWG Okey. I get stuck up on details like that so I would like to know haha. And if the case is that there is a char[] behind it then what std::string does to me is just act as a pointer to it? If I would append characters to this string a lot the complexity would go crazy then?

Comment: @o11c size in this case is the original size of the Tag inside the music file, meaning if I change the actual tag and it gets longer I know how much more padding is required in the file during the transfer. So size could probably be named better but that's essentially what it is.

Comment: @Simon No, the complexity wouldn't go crazy. `std::string`s have some space reserved for some new characters. If they run out of that, they allocate some more. That being said, you should do stuff that makes sense performance wise, but seriously don't think too much about it.

Comment: @Simon in that case, you should consider store it in the data structure that *contains* this one. But it does depend on the problem.

Comment: @Simon And yes, it just acts as a pointer, but it will also automatically allocate, deallocate, copy, and provide additional functions. That is why we use `std::string` instead of `char*`

Comment: @BWG Okey I guess I'm just thinking too much haha... Because when I did this assignment before I ended up with the least efficient program in the world so when profiling it later in the course I ended up speeding it up and improving it incredibly much and it just stuck with me, those thoughts :) But thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your default constructor already takes care of this. Your `std::string`s will initialize to empty string `""`. You can assign a different value to 
this `string` at any time.

If you really wanted to, you could change your default constructor to

```
Tag() : name(""), data(""), size(0) {}
```

Comment: And you really should make sure to initialize at least `size`

Comment: I'm just confusing myself and you guys even more I think. Because yeah.. I think too much. But yes you are right but no, I had another issue but BWG has clarified it for me so I think I will just delete this post if possible because my question doesn't really make sense compared to what I actually wanted... which I didn't know until after I asked it... kind of? Thanks though!